# pandas get columns without copy

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with multiple columns, and I want to get some of them, and drop others, without copying a new dataframe

I suppose it should be

```
df = df['col_a','col_b']
```

but I'm not sure whether it copy a new one or not. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should work, apart from one minor issue:

```
df = df['col_a','col_b']
```

shoud be:

```
df = df[['col_a','col_b']]
```

Because you assign the subset df back to df, it's essentially equivalent to dropping the other columns.

If you would like to drop other columns in place, you can do:

```
df.drop(columns=df.columns.difference(['col_a','col_b']),inplace=True)
```

Comment: will this copy a new dataframe or inplace?  Actually I just want to drop other columns except col_a and col_b, do it inplace, because I have very large dataframe and I don't want to copy a new dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you want.

you have a dataframe df with multiple columns a, b, c, d and e. You want to select let us say a and b and store them back in df. To achieve this, you can do :

```
      df=df[['a', 'b']]
```

Input dataframe df:

```
        a b c d e
        1 1 1 1 1
        3 2 3 1 4
```

When you do :

```
      df=df[['a', 'b']]
```

output will be :

```
     a b
     1 1
     3 2
```